# Missing asterisk in the label of the required field in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with displaying required fields in Cakephp 2.4.2.

If I use

```
$this->Form->input('username');
```

in rendered html I have

```
<div class="input text required">
    <label for="UserUsername">Username</label>
    <input name="data[User][username]" type="text" id="UserUsername" required="required"/>
</div>
```

and the label has asterisk: username*

If I want to use Twitter Bootstrap with its horizontal form style, my input changes to something like this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-xs-3"></label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <?php echo $form->input('username',array('id' => 'username','label' => false)); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which results in

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-xs-3">Username</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input text required">
                <input name="data[User][username]" id="username" type="text" required="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and label lost asterisk: username

Basically, if Cake input has option 'label' => false it will have input label without asterisk:

```
$this->Form->label('User.username');
$this->Form->input('username',array('label' => false));
```

results in

```
<label for="UserUsername">Username</label>
<div class="input text required">
    <input name="data[User][username]" type="text" id="UserUsername" required="required"/>
</div>
```

and no asterisk in the label.

What would be the way to have asterisk in the label of the required field while using Cake Form Helper?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out [Boost Cake](https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake) plugin for twitter bootstrap integration with CakePHP.

Comment: I'll take a look at suggested plugin, but still remains the question of label which slips out of div which contains input regardless link through "for".

Comment: Boostrap's nesting of tags and css classes are pretty different from CakePHP, so it's not surprising that you don't get similar display when using bootstrap.

Comment: Even without Bootstrap, if I use Form Helper and 'label' => false option, label stays out of div, and has no asterisk. Is there any workaround except not using Form Helper?

Comment: use Boost Cake and you can update the FormHelper file to include * when the input is required. Or you can explicitly specify the label text. That will auto generate all of the HTML you wrapped around that php/cakephp script. One stone used to kill two birds :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and just searching how to display the asterisk on all required inputs, (when using the BoostCake plugin), this css worked for me:

```
.required label:after {
    color: #d00;
    content: " *"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the way to have asterisk in the label of the required field while using Cake Form Helper?

Are you trying to hardcode an asterisk in the label? This should do the trick

```
$this->Form->input('username', array('label'=> 'Enter username here*'));
```

Comment: Actually no, I'd like to have $this->Form->label('User.username');
$this->Form->input('username',array('label' => false)); and that label gets * if the field is required.